# Как закрыть прямой доступ к файлам в папке через .htaccess, но разрешить если есть ?key=secret?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, доступ

Нужно запретить прямой URL-доступ к файлам из папки **orders** на сервере, при этом разрешить доступ по URL'у который содержит определенную GET-переменную *key* с значением: **secret**.

Вот к примеру, есть у нас папка **orders** и в ней файл **1.*** - расширение может быть любым, например **1.jpg**

Нужно чтобы обращение через **/orders/1.jpg** - выдавало бы ошибку доступа или переадресацию в 404
И наоборот обращение вида: **/orders/1.jpg?key=secret** было бы успешным!

Возможно ли такое реализовать с помощью настроек в **.htaccess**?

**p.s.:** а в идеале если бы еще можно было secret как-то генерировать - чтобы везде был бы не просто одинаковый **?key=secret**, а какой-нить **?key=ХХХХХХХ**, где ХХХХХХХ какой-нибудь кэш от имени файла к которому идет обращение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Возможно ли такое реализовать с помощью настроек в .htaccess?

Сделать подобное можно, но я бы (если бы был фронтенд девелопером) делал бы такое с помощью движка сайта.

Можете попробовать такой вариант:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/orders/.*
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^key=secret$
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: спасибо, а если это нужно распространить на подпапки внутри orders - как тогда поменяется правило?

Comment: @Enshtein отредактировал ответ. Но я не уверен в его пригодности на все случаи жизни.

Comment: Спасибо! Всё отлично!